# Can't set axis scale to logarithmic in 3D plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I would like to 3D plot the surface of a data 2d array with dimension [50,250]. Two of the axes (`x, z`) should be in logarithmic scale. Here's a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
xx = np.asanyarray([np.ones([250])*(m+1) for m in range(50)])
yy = np.asanyarray([range(250) for m in range(50)])
zz = np.asanyarray([np.sqrt(np.arange(250)*m) for m in range(50)])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.yaxis.set_scale('log')
```

All other answers I found indicate that this last line should do the trick. Instead, it raises the following `AttributeError: 'YAxis' object has no attribute 'set_scale'`

I don't get why it does so. I have the latest version of matplotlib installed in my Mac Osx 10.9.7 (that is 2.1.0).

Can anybody assist me on this one?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209) (though it is quite an old)

Comment: Especially the [workaround](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209#issuecomment-138667884) should work here as well.

Comment: ya, that's how I circumvented the issue. Thanks people