# 3D scatter with two axes in logscale

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to get a scatter plot with 2 axes (x,z) in a log scale using set_scale but that doesn't work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0,500,10)
y=np.linspace(0,1,10)
z=np.linspace(0,100000,10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.plot(x, y, z,'o', c='g')
ax.grid()

#ax.set_xscale('log')
#ax.set_zscale('log')
#ax.set_xlim([min(x), max(x)])
#ax.set_zlim([min(z), max(z)])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Check the comments in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891692/cant-set-axis-scale-to-logarithmic-in-3d-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!